# Fragments, Activities, FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I've read many posts on stackoverflow about fragments vs activities, but I'm not sure I understand. Am posting a problem I'm working on -- hopefully some of you could help me clarify what they mean in this context.

I want to build an app with two tabs: "take photo" and "browse photo". In take photo, the user can take a photo. In browse photo, the user can browse photos already taken.

So I've made two tabs so far in MainActivity, which extends FragmentActivity and implements ActionBar.TabListener. onCreate of MainActivity creates a SectionsPagerAdapter, which extends from FragmentPagerAdapter. The main purpose of my SectionsPagerAdapter is to create new Fragments. It creates a TakePhotoFragment and a BrowsePhotosFragment.

Question: in TakePhotoFragment, should I create a new activity that takes the photo? I do know how to create an activity that allows the user to take a photo, but not sure if this is right in this case. I did read that fragments are primarily for UI reasons and sit within activities, so it seems kind of weird to create an activity in a fragment (and also I don't know how this could be done).

I guess the main problem I'm facing is that I'm really confused about how activities and fragments can be used, despite all the reading I've done about them. Perhaps someone can help elucidate in the context of what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually fragments are used just to replace the views. It will be helpful while implementing sherlock Action Bar or Action Bar. Check it out here to have clear view about fragments concept first http://www.androidbegin.com/

Comment: Fragments are _not_ used to replace views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just some clarification, a fragment is a content that be put into an activity, not an activity. You will always have one Activity which can host fragments but not the other way.
For the camera thing, it's like using any other feature, you will call an external activity or service, you can do that inside the fragment, just like voice recognition or barcode scan.
Here is a simple example you can try, and adapt it for a fragment.
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
Hope it helps, good luck with your research .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you CAN'T create an Activity inside a Fragment.

If you have a code which works within an activity it should also work within a fragment. Just use the fragment's onCreateView instead of Activity's onCreate.

If you use some kind of SurfaceView for taking photos it works within any context. If you call an outer camera intent it has nothing to do with your layout, it just calls the device's photo app, so you can't put it inside your fragment.